# I have set value for cell of UITableView but why it didn't display?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created a UITableView and a UITableVIewCell in Main.storyboard and set it's dataSource and delegate to ViewController .Why UITableView didn't display texts when I run the **code**.
Another question is that does UITableView load before ViewLoad? If not why in func didRecieveResults() the Array of tableData can achieve datas but in func tableView()  it was nil

The whole codes as following

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,HttpProtocol {
    @IBOutlet weak var tv: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var iv: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var playTime: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

    var eHttp:HttpController = HttpController()
    var tableData:NSArray = NSArray()
    var channelData:NSArray = NSArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        eHttp.delegate = self
        eHttp.onSearch("http://www.douban.com/j/app/radio/channels")
        eHttp.onSearch("http://douban.fm/j/mine/playlist?channel=0")

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        println("tableData.count:\(channelData)")
        return 10
     }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell!{
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle,reuseIdentifier:"douban")
        let rowData:NSDictionary = self.tableData[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
        cell.textLabel!.text = "hehehehe"//rowData["title"] as! String
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "adasdasda"//rowData["artist"] as! String
        return cell
     }
    func didRecieveResults(results:NSDictionary){
        if (results["song"] != nil){

            self.tableData = results["song"] as! NSArray
            println(tableData)

        }else if (results["channels"] != nil){
            self.channelData = results["channels"] as! NSArray
         //   println(channelData)
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: you're missing one line. return cell

Comment: if the above comment doesnt help you please add the whole class code

Comment: Both answers are correct , I just want to add that you should also provide **UITablveViewDataSource** connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lukas points out, you need to return the `UITableViewCell` at the end of the method.

In fact, what you posted shouldn't even compile, so I'm wondering if you posted your sample code incorrectly.

The first thing to try, and actually return the cell, update your code to:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell!
{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle,reuseIdentifier:"douban")
    let rowData:NSDictionary = self.tableData[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    cell.textLabel!.text = "hehehehe"//rowData["title"] as! String
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "adasdasda"//rowData["artist"] as! String

    // YOU ARE MISSING THIS LINE
    return cell
}
```

Also ensure that you `UITableViewDatasource` is set properly, and that the required methods are functioning.  Specifically, both `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView` need to be returning values greater than 0.  (In the code you posted, you are missing `numberOfSectionsInTableView`)

Answer (score 1):

As Lukas said in a comment, you should make sure you return a value from your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method otherwise it will refuse to build. If you've done that and you still don't see any cells, it's probably because either `numberOfRowsInSection` or `numberOfSectionsInTableView` are returning 0, so you should make sure they return a positive integer.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to copy return cell,not this reason

Comment: I've put in an edit request to say this. Can you confirm you're definitely returning a positive integer for the two methods I mentioned?

Comment: Thanks ,you are right ,numberOfRowsInSection return 0